# How to handle promise on success or on error

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, ionic-framework, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I wrote an ionic app. I started adding tests to it I'm facing a problem with `$resources`. In this case I have this Controller :

```js
.controller('newAccountCtrl', function($scope, $window, $rootScope, API, $ionicPopup, $state) {
  $scope.newData = {};
  $scope.$on('$ionicView.enter', function() {

    $scope.newData = {};
  });
  $scope.newInfo = function() {
    API.newAccountInfo.update({
      restCode: $scope.newData.restore_code
    }, $scope.newData, function(res, header) {
      $scope.comty = 'update';
      $window.location.href = '#/login';
    }, function(err) {
      if (err.data == null)
        $rootScope.popup("Error", "no connection");
      else
        $rootScope.popup('error', err.data.error);
    });
  }
})
```

And in the service I make a request using `$resources` in function :

```js
angular.module('starter.services', [])
  .factory('API', function($rootScope, $resource, $ionicPopup, $ionicLoading, $window) {
      return {
        newAccountInfo: $resource(base + '/restoreinfo/:restCode', {
          restCode: '@_restCode'
        }, {
          update: {
            method: 'PUT'
          }
        }, {
          stripTrailingSlashes: false
        });
      }
```

and in the my test the following code:

```js
describe('newAccountCtrl', function() {

  var controller,
    deferredLogup, window, scope,
    $rootScope,
    $q, store, API,
    PROMISE = {
      resolve: true,
      reject: false
    };
  beforeEach(angular.mock.module('starter'));
  beforeEach(module('starter.controllers'));
  beforeEach(module('starter.services'));
  beforeEach(module(function($provide, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $provide.value('$ionicTemplateCache', function() {});
    $urlRouterProvider.deferIntercept();
  }));

  beforeEach(inject(function($controller, _$rootScope_, $q, _API_, _$window_) {
    $q = $q;

    deferredLogup = $q.defer();
    $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
    spyOn($rootScope, 'popup')
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    API = _API_;
    window = _$window_;

    spyOn(API.newAccountInfo, 'update').and.callThrough(function(callback) {
      deferredLogup.promise.then(callback);
      return deferredLogup.promise;
    });

    controller = $controller('newAccountCtrl', {
      '$scope': scope,
      'API': API,
      '$window': window
    });

  }));
  it('expect API.newAccountInfo to Have Been Called', function() {
    scope.getloghist();
    expect(API.newAccountInfo.upadate).toHaveBeenCalled();
  })

  it('on success ', function() {
    scope.newInfo();
    deferredLogup.resolve();
    scope.$digest();
    expect(scope.comty).toBeDefined();
  });

  it('on unsuccessful', function() {
    scope.newInfo();
    deferredLogup.reject();
    scope.$digest()
    expect($rootScope.popup).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

first expect it pass , but the second one "on success" return with error

> "Expected undefined to be defined".

I'm new to writing unit tests. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your spy:

```
spyOn(API.newAccountInfo, 'update').and.callThrough(function(callback){
  deferredLogup.promise.then(callback);
  return deferredLogup.promise;
});
```

`.and.callThrough` only tracks the function. It does not mock it (thus the function you pass it is doing nothing). From the docs:

> By chaining the spy with and.callThrough, the spy will still track all calls to it but in addition it will **delegate to the actual implementation.**

Which is fancy talk for 'it runs the actual function that you're spying on'.

Looks like you want `.and.callFake` which tracks and mocks with the passed function.

## Edit because it looks like there's more than one thing wrong:

```
spyOn(API.newAccountInfo,'update').and.callFake(function(callback){
  deferredLogup.promise.then(callback);
  return deferredLogup.promise;
});
```

So, you're mocking with this anonymous function:

```
function(callback){
  deferredLogup.promise.then(callback);
  return deferredLogup.promise;
}
```

This^ function is now acting as `API.newAccountInfo.update`. This function takes its **first** parameter and runs it as a callback. Go look at where you're running `API.newAccountInfo.update`:

```
API.newAccountInfo.update({
  restCode: $scope.newData.restore_code
}, $scope.newData, function(res, header) {
  $scope.comty = 'update';
  $window.location.href = '#/login';
}, function(err) {
  if (err.data == null)
    $rootScope.popup("Error", "no connection");
  else
    $rootScope.popup('error', err.data.error);
});

//Simplifying this:

API.newAccountInfo.update([Object], [Object], successCallback, errorCallback)
```

You're passing the callback as the **third** and **fourth** parameters, not the first one. But your mock is trying to run the **first** parameter. So it's trying to feed an object (not a function) into `deferredLogup.promise.then`.

Your spy should look like this:

```
spyOn(API.newAccountInfo,'update').and.callFake(function(param1, param2, callback, errorCallback){
  deferredLogup.promise.then(callback);
  return deferredLogup.promise;
});
```

Hopefully that helps.

Comment: Hallo,I replace callThrought by callFake and the same error appears **"Expected undefined to be defined"**.

Comment: I edited my answer. Not sure if that completely fixes your problem but it should get you closer.